# How to move data/rows between databases with the same structure with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Now, I have 2 databases (users and productions), but we focus on DB_production, which I would like to make a copy of (data structure only). And in this case, I think that the only compromise would be to make changes in both databases, if there are structural changes to the tables.

To keep DB_production as "clean" as possible and to run smoothly, I want to move the records that are no longer "current" to another database. But the rows can be inserted back into DB_production at any time.

The DB_production copy will be called DB_archive (so, the same structure).
*Local info: '10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2', 'InnoDB', 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci', 'utf8mb4'*

To move a record from **table1** in DB_production to **table1** in DB_archive, I can use:

```
INSERT INTO DB_archive.table1 
SELECT * FROM DB_production.table1 WHERE id_table1 = 10
```

then

```
DELETE FROM DB_production.table1 WHERE id_table1 = 10
```

and vice versa to move records back.

[image: example db structure]

### BUT

the table **table1** has many relationships (one-to-one, one-to-many) with 15 other tables.

1. To move records from tables that are related to table1, should I use the same method?
   to do this, do I have to lock the database until I move the records from the rest of the tables?
2. Is there a better solution?

## When this happens

1. the user can do this action at any time,
2. a cron job (which will run outside working hours), will select older recordings, e.g. 3 months that will be moved to DB_archive

---

I tried to use table partitioning, but I don't think that this method helps me much.

Comment: I built [Fregata](https://github.com/AymDev/Fregata) for this kind of purposes: move data from any source to any destination. You can use it [as a Symfony Bundle](https://github.com/AymDev/FregataBundle) to run your *migrations* asynchronously (using Symfony Messenger) from the UI or the CLI. I won't post an answer to avoid promoting it but would love to get feedback if you use it.

Comment: Not the best idea to use versions which reached end of life in production.

Comment: @GeorgRichter Agree, this version is from my local server.

Comment: I would challenge the overarching premise to begin with; when configured appropriately, database systems are designed to handle absolutely massive amounts of data with little to no impact on performance - I don't see a practical reason to "*keep DB_production as "clean" as possible*" unless I am missing some more context. A big reason for using an RDBMS in the first place is that your tables have relationships that are enforced by the DB engine - this will significantly complicate the extraction and re-load of the data. (1/2)

Comment: You must also consider that database schemas evolve over time to meet the changing needs of the application it's supporting; by doing this you are setting yourself up for headaches in the future when you want to move data between servers and the schemas don't align anymore. I would strongly recommend re-evaluating this requirement - the cost/benefit does not quite add up here. (2/2)

Comment: @esqew  I agree with this: "_when configured appropriately, database systems are designed to handle absolutely massive amounts of data ..._" but my database it was not quite well designed from the beginning.

Comment: @vmar Ok, but that begs the question - why make an effort to further convolute the design from generally-accepted best practices and the way the DBs themselves were designed to be used by going this route, instead of the rather obvious choice of fixing the database design itself to properly support scalability?

Comment: @esqew Ok, your question is correct. Now, in order to find a good solution for my issue, I have to look for several options and choose the best one. I still don't know how easy or complicated what I asked in the OP could be. That's why I'm looking for an answer.
And maybe I didn't say it right... the database could be fixed, but the application (written in PHP) would be more difficult to optimize.